# PostgreSQL PITR not working properly

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pitr

I am trying to restore a PostgreSQL database to a point in time.

When I am using only `restore_command` in `recovery.conf` then its working fine.

```
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/pg_log_archive/%f %p'
```

When I am using the `recovery_target_time parameter`, it is not restoring to the target time.

```
restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/pgsql/pg_log_archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_time='2018-06-05 06:43:00.0'
```

Below is the log file content:

```
2018-06-05 07:31:39.166 UTC [22512] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-06-05 06:35:52 UTC
2018-06-05 07:31:39.664 UTC [22512] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2018-06-05 06:43:00+00
2018-06-05 07:31:39.671 UTC [22512] LOG:  restored log file "00000005.history" from archive
2018-06-05 07:31:39.769 UTC [22512] LOG:  restored log file "00000005000000020000008F" from archive
2018-06-05 07:31:39.816 UTC [22512] LOG:  redo starts at 2/8F000028
2018-06-05 07:31:39.817 UTC [22512] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 2/8F000130
2018-06-05 07:31:39.818 UTC [22510] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2018-06-05 07:31:39.912 UTC [22512] LOG:  restored log file "000000050000000200000090" from archive
2018-06-05 07:31:39.996 UTC [22512] LOG:  recovery stopping before abort of transaction 9525, time 2018-06-05 06:45:02.088502+00
2018-06-05 07:31:39.996 UTC [22512] LOG:  recovery has paused
```

I am trying to restore the database instance to 06:43:00. Why is it recovering up to 06:45:02?

**EDIT**

In first scenario recovery.conf converted into recovery.done but this didn't happen in second scenario

What could be the reason of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to set

```
recovery_target_action = 'promote'
```

After point-in-time-recovery, [`recovery_target_action`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-target-settings.html#RECOVERY-TARGET-ACTION) determines how PostgreSQL will proceed.

The default value is `pause` which means that PostgreSQL will do nothing and wait for you to tell it how to proceed.

To complete recovery, connect to the database and run

```
SELECT pg_wal_replay_resume();
```

It seems that there has been no database activity logged between 06:43:00 and 06:45:02. Observe that the log says `recovery stopping before abort of transaction 9525`.

Comment: YogeshR specified 06:43:00 as the stop point, and it actually stopped before abort of transaction 9525, so what's the exact logic or definition of the actual recovery stopping point, would you help to explain?

Comment: @QiuYangfan It stops at the first transaction > or >= the recovery target, depending on `recovery_target_inclusive`.

Comment: great thanks! Is that true that with recovery_target_time=T1, the PITR would replay some lsn further than T1 but before the next transaction end?

Comment: No, I said it *stops* there. It will never replay anything from *after* the recovery target.

Comment: Hmm, seems in my case with an idle Postgres, I get timestamp at T1, and drop table at T1+d, and execute recovery with recovery_target_time=T1, and the table is recovey but locked. I'm confused if the stop point is T1, why the table is locked?

Comment: @QiuYangfan Because it was locked at that time. You should start a new question for that.